# How to return an object with multiple types

Tags: java, list, collections, random-access

Let's take an example to make it easier. I build a list which the constructor takes an `integer` and a `List<Integer>`. My list will contains all the elements of the given list multiplied by the `integer`. My list does not store the new elements but compute them on the fly:

```java
class MyList extends AbstractList<Integer> implements RandomAccess {
    private final int multiplier;
    private final List<Integer> list;

    public MyList(int multiplier, List<Integer> list) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(int index) {
        return list.get(index) * multiplier;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Then we can call `new MyList(3, list)` with `list = [0, 1, 2, 3]` to get `[0, 3, 6, 9]`.

I would like to limit the developer to give to the `MyList` constructor a list which is also `RandomAccess`, to be sure he will not ruin performances.

I tried to change the constructor with:

```java
public <E extends List<Integer> & RandomAccess> MyList(int multiplier, E list)
```

`MyList` is not the issue but now we cannot invoke the constructor without using an implementation of both `List<Integer>` and `RandomAccess` like `ArrayList<Integer>`. So someone who have this list: `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();` cannot do `new MyList(3, list);` (Because it is declared with `List<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`).

The other solution I have is this one:

```java
public MyList(int multiplier, List<Integer> list) {
        if(!(list instanceof RandomAccess)) {
            // Do something like log or throw exception
        }
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
        this.list = list;
    }
```

But now I cannot check at compile time if the list implements `RandomAccess`, and I need to use `instanceof` and I hate doing this.

I'm pretty sure there is a better way but what is it?

Comment: Try using | (or operator) instead of the & (and operator). I'm not sure if this will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: So if you want to limit the developer to `RandomAccess` _"to be sure he will not ruin performances"_, then why would you still want to allow them to invoke your constructor with `List`, which clearly doesn't implement `RandomAccess`? Is this just for cosmetic reason?

Comment: I need to call `List.get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adopt the solution used by `Collections.unmodifiableList`. Instead of a public constructor, have a static method that returns one of two implementations, one implementing `RandomAccess`, the other not.

Here is the code for `Collections.unmodifiableList`.

```
public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list) {
    return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new UnmodifiableRandomAccessList<>(list) :
            new UnmodifiableList<>(list));
}
```

I know you said you don't like using `instanceof`. Neither do I, but sometimes it's the best thing to do.

Note that the solution using the constructor

```
public <E extends List<Integer> & RandomAccess> MyList(int multiplier, E list)
```

is not just ugly, in that it forces the programmer to cast (e.g. to an `ArrayList`), but it wouldn't actually work. For example, if `list` is an instance of `Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList`, it would not even be possible to cast  it to a type implementing both `List` and `RandomAccess`, because `Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` is private.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `instanceof`. In fact this is exactly what the `RandomAccess` documentation suggests:

> Generic list algorithms are encouraged to check whether the given list
>   is an instanceof this interface before applying an algorithm that
>   would provide poor performance if it were applied to a sequential
>   access list, and to alter their behavior if necessary to guarantee
>   acceptable performance.

Your constructor could potentially have two implementations. If `RandomAccess` is implemented then it stores a reference to the `List` otherwise it creates a new `ArrayList` and copies all elements to it:

```
class MyList {
    private final int multiplier;
    private final List<Integer> list;

    public MyList(int multiplier, List<Integer> list) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
        if (list instanceof RandomAccess)
            this.list = list;
        else
            this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

    public int get(int index) {
        return multiplier * list.get(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer and pbabcdefp's are good enough for me. I store some data if only I need to. So I would like to prevent the developer he should use a List which implements RandomAccess. Is there a programmatic way to do this? Or the only alternative I have is javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

If *your* class needs a random access list, then *your class* should deal with that and not push your class's needs onto the caller. Further, it would be simpler to do the multiplication in the constructor - you have to do it at some point, but doing it early means you can throw away lots of code:

```
class MyList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    public MyList(int multiplier, List<Integer> list) {
        for (Integer i : list)
            add(i * multiplier);
    }
}
```

That's all you need, *and* it is safer: with your immemtation, both your list and the caller have a reference to the list. If after invoking the constructor the calling changes the list, other code using the multiplied list will unexpectedly see values in the list change.

Comment: Your assumption that 'you have to do it at some point' could well be false. It's entirely possible that this is a list of many items in which very few are actually ever accessed (hence the need for random access).

Comment: @sprinter I just did a performance test: running this code with an input list size of 10 random numbers took less than 5 microseconds (on an average PC, after warm up) to create the new list of multiplied numbers - that's 0.0000005 seconds per element. I don't know about you, but I can live with that "performance hit" to purge all that code.

Comment: By many items I meant many millions. Frankly if you have 10 item in a list then the data structure doesn't much matter.

Comment: Moreover you suggest me to store the elements of the list and I'm trying to avoid that. And I cannot assume a `O(n)` constructor. This solution could be implemented through a static factory method.